# Allow specifying minimum monthly and daily compensation, in addition to annual compensation

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-page

Currently it's only possible to specify a minimum *annual* compensation in the Job Match Preferences. When discussing temporary contracts, at least here in Belgium, compensation is always a daily rate.

Can you add the possibility to select the granularity? Ideally I'd be able to set the compensation per contract type, because for a permanent contract it's more common to discuss a monthly/yearly salary.

Employers will also have to be able to choose the granularity then, of course.

Comment: @JNat That seems to be a different page? Or is that part of a larger change to the profile settings?

Comment: It should be a free-text field on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) too — which I assume is what you are referring to?

Comment: @JNat Yes, that's the page, but I'm not seeing a free-text field: http://i.imgur.com/iu8nx2j.png

Comment: Oh! I misread the intent of the post, then. I read "more granularity" as "more granularity in the minimum compensation," and not as more granularity in the _denominator_ there. Reopening the question.

Comment: @JNat thanks, got a bit confused myself there :)